# Using SAPUI5 Portal roles in Java backend

Tags: sapui5

I am creating a planning application in SAPUI5 and deploying it to a portal site. I'm using two roles (PlanningUserRole & PlanningAdminRole). Can I somehow retrieve the role of the user in the SAPUI5 application so I can pass it on to the Java backend?

I've tried the code below, but it doesn't give me any information regarding the roles.

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getUser();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I added SCP Portal roles and the Java application roles to an Authorization Group (Security --> Authorization --> Groups). I named them both the same. The only difference is the origin. But it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

in order for using this service you have to bootstrap the ushell as described in this document https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.6/docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.html

```
    <script src="/sap/public/bc/ui5_ui5/resources/sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js"></script>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src=".../sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```